# why is it efficient to use viewWithTag?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];

    UIImage * box = [UIImage imageNamed: @"box.png"];
    UIView * cellbackgroundview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(7, 0, box.size.width, box.size.height)];
    [cellbackgroundview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: box]];

    UILabel * nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 15, box.size.width, 19.0f)];
    nameLabel.text = name;
    [nameLabel setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0f/255.0f green:79.0f/255.0f blue:79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [nameLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 18.0f]];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    nameLabel.tag = 1;
    .....

}

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1]).text = name;
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2]).text = pitch;
```

Why is it efficient to use viewWithTag as I did above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I disagree with the answers. I think using tags is not a good practice in general, and on your case, it's only laziness. You should be creating an `UITableViewCell` subclass, with the labels as properties.

Mike Keller [wrote a post about it](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html):

> Let’s assume you aren’t trying to store data in a view’s tag. Instead, you just want a quick and dirty way to grab a reference to a view. Is it OK to use tags in these situations?
>
> Well, in almost every case I can think of, it is better to store a reference to the view using a real property somewhere, whether that’s an IBOutlet or just a regular property on your class.
>
> Do you need to add some custom views to a UITableViewCell? Subclass it and add real properties. (...)
>
> By using real properties you get stronger typing, better naming, better visibility of the moving parts of your app, and you don’t have to down-cast viewWithTag’s UIView* return type. You also get better performance because viewWithTag: must traverse the view hierarchy for every call.
>
> To me, using tags seems to be another pattern driven purely by laziness.

Answer (score 9):

Who said it's efficient? In what context?

It isn't really efficient because it performs a search of the view hierarchy to find the view. The efficient option is to create a cell subclass which has properties for the views you want to access and then you can get the references without any searching.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're not really asking about the efficiency, but rather asking about efficacy (i.e. why do it this way).

You're using `viewWithTag` if the cell was successfully dequeued/reused so you can still access the appropriate `UILabel` objects you added when the cell was first created. You're doing that for functional reasons (because you don't want to re-add controls that are already in the reused cell).

So, yes, this is a fine technique: Assign a `tag` to designate a label being for a particular purpose in the cell when the cell is first created, but use `viewWithTag` to quickly identify that label at a later point in the app when the cell is reused. I wouldn't describe this as being done for efficiency's sake as much as just to ensure you don't unnecessarily create redundant controls in a reused cell.

It's worth noting that while this technique was not uncommon a few years ago, nowadays there are more elegant approaches that eliminate cryptic `tag` numbers and result in more legible code through the use of storyboard cell prototypes and `UITableViewCell` subclasses.

But there's nothing wrong with your technique. It's just that it wouldn't generally be singled out as especially efficient, and, nowadays, code legibility reasons might lean people towards other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, without seeing the rest of your code, it doesn't make much sense using tag with a UITableView. And there are also few other things I would correct.

However, there are many other cases where using tags is preferred. In my case I have an app which is creating a few UIViews on the fly and add them as subviews on existing UIViews on screen. Rather than getting strong reference here and there, I am just assigning and keeping a custom tag to recall the UIView anytime.

I think that:

```
[myView viewWithTag:BACKGROUND_CONSTANT]
```

is quite readable, and avoid me to write subclasses or class extensions that bloat my project.

Also, I understand the searching of performance, but nowadays compared to the past (a remote past) devices are quite powerful, so don't be worry by stressing the system with works and tasks. A best practice is to always run a profiler (XCode has a good one), measure and solve problems if any.